Adding holiday parameter into NetworkDays function
I would like seek assistance with the NetworkDays function.
I am interested in the last parameter containing holidays. So far I managed to get it working with ranges of cells in a worksheet, however, I would like to avoid referencing cells.
Is there a possibility to use arrays? So far all my attempts have been unsuccessful.
I tried to define:
Dim holidayDates() as Variant
holidayDates = Array(DateSerial(2023,1,1),DateSerial(2023,12,25))

and so on with many dates in between
Then I would call
WorksheetFunction.NetworkDays(.Cells(3,3).Value, .Cells(3,3).Value, holidayDates)

to check for a single day if it is either a weekend or a public holiday. However, this approach does not work. The cell (3,3) contains a date in a non-serial format which works fine without the holiday parameter.
I have also tried using a string with serial date values separated by commas instead but it did not work either. E.g. DateSerial(2023,1,1) & "," & DateSerial(2023,12,25) and so on.
Both approaches have been tested with a normal date format as well as with the DateSerial function.

"this approach does not work" - how is the result different from what you expect?

Try using the number that the date represents (ex.: 41268 for Dec 15, 2012,)

Not sure what you mean by "does not work". Your algorithm and code works fine here to return a 0 if the date (duplicated as start and end dates) is in the holidayDates array, or if it is a weekend day.

What, exactly, do you mean by date in a non-serial format ? Dates are stored as numbers. How they are formatted should not be relevant. Serial format is not one of the listed format options for a cell.

@RonRosenfeld Non-serial format of a date could be e.g. 01.01.2024, that was what I meant.

DateSerial return value (this is a date type) has to be converted to a double type.

Dim holidayDates() As Variant
holidayDates = Array(CDbl(DateSerial(2023, 1, 1)), CDbl(DateSerial(2023, 12, 25)))
With ActiveSheet
WorksheetFunction.NetworkDays .Cells(3, 3).Value, .Cells(3, 3).Value, holidayDates
End With



Seems to work without any issues here, using the date data type for the holiday days.

Unable to get the NetworkDays property of the WorksheetFunction class is returned for me without CDbl. Weird.

I copy/pasted your code and it ran without an error without the CDbl with C3 either empty or containing a date.

Varietas delectat.

@RonRosenfeld Hi Black cat, Ron, I had the same issue/error (apologies, Ron, for not posting its message earlier I am still new to the forum) as Black cat, that is why I posted my question here. I did not think of date serial being a double type parameter for the NetworkDays function. However, for some strange reason today it does work without CDbl. It is strange and I do not know the reason. I would like to thank both of you, Ron and Black cat - you have indeed solved my issue and saved me.

@Blackcat Adding you as well. Thank you!
